# How will Selenium handle dynamically generated pages / complex DOM hierarchies in future?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to write Test Automation scripts using Selenium, but the page elements are not structured in the traditional way - i.e. in a strict hierarchy. Elements which are directly below other elements on the Page are not following those elements in the DOM, therefore it's impossible to relate/link one element on a page to another using an xpath expression.

In a tool like Sahi, i can create relational identifiers using Sahi's above/below/left/right API functions.

Is there any proposal to introduce such methods in Selenium now that DOM's are so dynamic and complex?

Is anyone aware of alternative tools or libraries which overcome the above described issues?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in finding out what **Feature Requests** the Selenium team is currently working on, please visit https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium.

If you have a current issue that you believe needs resolved, please create a *NEW ISSUE* [Here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues).

> In a tool like Sahi, i can create relational identifiers using Sahi's above/below/left/right API functions.

If you are looking for some of these features from Selenium, you can checkout [Helium](https://heliumhq.com/). It's a wrapper that makes using selenium a little easier and gives you access to things like *toLeftOf / toRightOf / above / below*.

Comment: Thank you very much! This looks like a library worth doing a Proof of Concept on.